# converting non Rest to Rest api

Tags: ruby, web-services, rest, http, architecture

I am writing a Rails server that provide REST api interface.

After many days I started it, a new requirement came up: there is the need to support a legacy android app client that make calls in a non REST way, so totally incompatible with the REST Server.

I thought that I could write a new server that converts the calls from the client to the REST Server, it would be an http server that makes other http calls.

The questions are, what is the technical name for that kind of "converter" I'd like to build? (so I can better google for it),
do you see other possible solutions or does it sound doable?

Comment: So, you want a proxy between a non-restful client and a restful service, I suppose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach of having a proxy in between seems to be an acceptable way to deal with the legacy support requirement. In addition it will isolate the REST API from any influence of architectural choices made in the old API.

However the downside of such a wrapper is that it will probably limit you in decisions you'll be able to make in future. Since with any change in REST API you'll have to adjust the legacy accordingly, which means double effort each time.

Also, most likely you'll have to deal with proxying security for the lagacy API through the REST API, which can lead to non-obvious pitfalls.

My suggestion is to port the legacy API and use it as it is till it gets discounted, unless the above won't work for your situation.